# Can I use the Halo: Anniversary map packs with Halo: Reach?

Tags: halo-reach, halo-anniversary

I purchased Halo: Anniversary recently and was told by a friend that the maps (which run off the Reach engine) can be downloaded for free for access from within Reach, since I own both Reach and Anniversary. I could not find online how to do this, so is this possible? And if so, how?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

When you buy Halo: Combat Evolved Anniversary, you get two components: the original campaign remastered, along with 6 multiplayer maps and 1 Firefight map using the Halo: Reach engine.

If don't own Halo: Reach, you can only play the maps included with Anniversary. There is a Multiplayer option on the title screen of Anniversary that boots up a minimal version of Halo: Reach - namely, only multiplayer with only Anniversary playlists available.

If you bought a new copy of Anniversary, it should have included a code that allows you to download the Anniversary Map Pack for Halo: Reach. Once you have done this, these maps work like any other map pack for Halo: Reach - they are available to play (whether in a custom game or in matchmaking) when you run Halo: Reach.

If you didn't buy Anniversary new (or only want the maps, and not the remastered campaign), the Anniversary Map Pack can be downloaded for 1200MS points.

Answer (score 0):

You can download the anniversary maps for free to use with Reach. A download code is located in the 'Halo: Annivesary' box.

Comment: Thanks, but the previous answer was more than sufficient. Unless you have new information, please don't answer a question